# Struts2 Map/Collection Validation

Tags: struts2, struts-validation

I am trying to do validation on a Map using struts 2. 
When I click on the submit button, the error message will always appear even though I have inserted a value into the textbox. 
Is there anyway for it to work? 
Any help will be much appreciated. 
The following is my file

In my new.jsp

```
<s:textfield name="myObject.myMap['name']" key="name" ></s:textfield>
```

In the validaton.xml

```
<validators> 
   <field name="myObject.myMap['name']"> 
      <field-validator type="requiredstring"> 
        <message key="errors.required"/> 
      </field-validator> 
   </field> 
</validators>
```

Comment: Is myObject.myMap['name'] rendering a value from entity? There might be some conversion error happening before validation interceptor and it is giving NULL value to the validator.

Comment: I have tried submitting without going through the validator and I am able to save the value into the database with auto injection. So I do not think it is returning null

Comment: Is your validate() method empty? Also, can you show us your interceptors stack?